# Get data from dataset in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am new in `webservice`. I am consuming a `.net webservice` in my `php application`. its working but my result is in dataset form. how can I get data from this. my result is :

```
Array ( [WebmethodName] => 
    Array ( [schema] => 
       Array ( [element] => 
         Array ( [complexType] => 
            Array ( [choice] => 
              Array ( [element] => 
                Array ( [complexType] => 
                   Array ( [sequence] => 
                      Array ( [element] => 
                        Array ( [0] => Array ( [!name] => G101 [!minOccurs] => 0 ) 
                                [1] => Array ( [!name] => G102 [!minOccurs] => 0 ) 
                                [2] => Array ( [!name] => G103 [!minOccurs] => 0 ) 
                                [3] => Array ( [!name] => G104 [!minOccurs] => 0 )
                                [4] => Array ( [!name] => G105 [!minOccurs] => 0 ) 
                                [5] => Array ( [!name] => G106 [!minOccurs] => 0 ) 
                                [6] => Array ( [!name] => G107 [!minOccurs] => 0 ) 
                                [7] => Array ( [!name] => G108 [!minOccurs] => 0 ) 
                                [8] => Array ( [!name] => G109 [!minOccurs] => 0 ) 
                                [9] => Array ( [!name] => G110 [!minOccurs] => 0 ) 
                                [10] => Array ( [!name] => G111 [!minOccurs] => 0 ) 
                                [11] => Array ( [!name] => G112 [!minOccurs] => 0 ) 
                             ) 
                          ) 
                     ) 
               [!name] => Table 
            ) 
         [!minOccurs] => 0 [!maxOccurs] => unbounded 
         ) 
     ) 
     [!name] => NewDataSet [!msdata:IsDataSet] => true [!msdata:UseCurrentLocale] => true ) [!id] => NewDataSet ) [diffgram] => Array ( [NewDataSet] => Array ( [Table] => Array ( [G101] => 5053.png [G102] => 118 [G103] => .png [G108] => 5055 [G109] => 2014-09-05T14:50:59+05:30 [!diffgr:id] => Table1 [!msdata:rowOrder] => 0 ) ) ) ) )
```

and i am calling this webservice like this.how can i find result from this.please help me.

```
<?php

    require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

    $wsdl = "url?wsdl";

    $mynamespace = "http://tempuri.org/";

    $theVariable = array('Id'=> '1022');

    $s = new SoapClient($wsdl,true);


    $result = $s->call('MethodName',array('parameters' =>  $theVariable));

    echo "<h1>Result:</h1>";

    echo "<pre>";


    print_r ($result);

        echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: take a loon on the documentation, http://in3.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php that helps you to short out the things related to array and a more better way to organize data.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple array, get data like this...

```
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
$wsdl        = "url?wsdl";
$mynamespace = "http://tempuri.org/";
$theVariable = array('Id'=> '1022');
$s           = new SoapClient($wsdl,true);
$result      = $s->call('MethodName',array('parameters' =>  $theVariable));

echo $result['WebmethodName']['schema']['element']['complexType']['choice']['element']['complexType']['sequence']['element'][0]['!name'];
//outputs eg G101
```

For shorter source, try it like this...

```
$users = $result['WebmethodName']['schema']['element']['complexType']['choice']['element']['complexType']['sequence']['element'];

foreach($users as $user){
    echo "Name: "      . $user['!name'] . "<br />";
    echo "MinOccurs: " . $user['!minOccurs'] . "<br /><br />";
}
```

will output some like

```
Name: G101
MinOccurs: 0

Name: G102
MinOccurs: 0

Name: G103
MinOccurs: 0

Name: G104
MinOccurs: 0

//and so on...
```